# Issues with existing from the navigation bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, exit

I have a user login activity once the user logs in he is redirected to navigation bar activity.

Problem : When the user is on the navigation bar activity and press back button - in this case the login screen pops ups again.

What I want : When the user clicks on the back button in the navigation screen the app should exit and it should not open the login screen.

Comment: whats your trying code?whats the output?

Comment: post your code please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you navigate the user to Navigation bar activity from login screen. then call `finish()` in login screen.

For example, do the following in your LoginActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, NavigationBarActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

It is happening because you haven't closed the Login Activity when you navigate the user to the Navigation bar activity. The Login Activity remains in the backstack and pops up on pressing the back button.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked by mistake I had put finish above start activity

Comment: Ok thanks I have accepted the above one as it was given first and I tried based on that it's just I replied to ur comments

Comment: @Brijesh Yes. It is. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

once the user loges in he is redirected to navigation bar activity.

When you redirect to Navigation Activity from Login Activity on successful login, please add one line below you `startActivity(intent)`, i.e. `finish()`.

For Ex:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavigationActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: BTW this is what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked by mistake I had put finish above start activity